# Oracle: Output of one query to input of another query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I need to join two queries output of 1st query should be the input for 2nd query in where clause, How do I achieve this?

```
Select
      Distinct
              TRNSFR_SRC_ID,
              DESCR_ORG,
              SUBJECT,
              CRSE_NBR,
              DESCR1_FRMVW,
              SUBJECT_TO,
              CATALOG_NBR_TO,

    FROM
              TRNSFR_CRSE
    WHERE
              ORG_ID = ?



    Select 
      Distinct 
              ATTR_VALUE
      From TRNSFR_CRSE
      Where 
              ORG_ID = ?
              and SUBJECT = ?
              and CRSE_NBR =  ?
              and SUBJECT_TO = ?
              and CATALOG_NBR_TO = ?
              and CRSE_ATTR = 'GHH'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle can make this really easy, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.  But something like this:

```
select Distinct ATTR_VALUE
from TRNSFR_CRSE
where (ORG_ID, SUBJECT, CRSE_NBR, SUBJECT_TO, CATALOG_NBR_TO) IN
          (Select TRNSFR_SRC_ID, SUBJECT, CRSE_NBR, SUBJECT_TO, CATALOG_NBR_TO
           from TRNSFR_CRSE
           where ORG_ID = ?
          ) and
       CRSE_ATTR = 'GHH'
```

You can use `=` rather than `in` if you know the subquery is supposed to return no more than one row.

Comment: ibelieve condition  and CRSE_ATTR = 'GHH'  is a part of main query and should be outside the brackets

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that the output of the 1st query is input to the second query then use below

```
Select 
  Distinct 
          ATTR_VALUE
  From TRNSFR_CRSE
  Where 
          (ORG_ID,SUBJECT,CRSE_NBR,SUBJECT_TO,,CATALOG_NBR_TO) in 
   (Select
         DESCR_ORG,
          SUBJECT,
          CRSE_NBR,
          SUBJECT_TO,
          CATALOG_NBR_TO,

FROM
          TRNSFR_CRSE
WHERE
          ORG_ID = ?)

          and CRSE_ATTR = 'GHH'"
```